# matplotlib graph shows up WITHOUT calling plt.show(), plt.show() doesn't display graph in separate cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I got confused for the code I have here, when I develop my code into different cells in Jupyter Notebook, I gradually notice that the matplotlib graph shows up without calling plt.show(), which is anti-intuitive to me.

So if you implement the script below, the graph will pop up without plt.show():

```
data = np.array([
[5,   3,  2 ],
[2,  -3,  5 ],
[ -4, 4, -6],
[-5, -3, -1],
[2,   6,   6]     
])
bar_markers = np.array([4, 3, -2, 2, -1])
index = np.arange(len(data[:, 0]))
width = 0.15

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(index, data[:,0], width, bottom = 0, color = 'yellowgreen')
ax.bar(index+width, data[:, 1], width, bottom = 0, color = 'purple')
ax.bar(index+2*width, data[:, 2], width, bottom = 0, color = np.random.rand(3,))
ax.bar(index+width, [0]*len(bar_markers), width*3, bottom=bar_markers, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

In a different word, this will cause confusion when you develop your code cell by cell in Jupyter Notebook, because 1)when you actually try to display graph using `plt.show()` in a different cell, it doesn't show any graph at all; 2) whenever you initialize graph using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` it will display an empty graph right away. What I mean is shown below:

```
# in the first cell in Jupyter Notebook
data = np.array([
[5,   3,  2 ],
[2,  -3,  5 ],
[ -4, 4, -6],
[-5, -3, -1],
[2,   6,   6]     
])
bar_markers = np.array([4, 3, -2, 2, -1])
index = np.arange(len(data[:, 0]))
width = 0.15

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Once implement it, the empty graph pops up without a reason.[image]

```
# Then when you keep coding in a different cell
ax.bar(index, data[:,0], width, bottom = 0, color = 'yellowgreen')
ax.bar(index+width, data[:, 1], width, bottom = 0, color = 'purple')
ax.bar(index+2*width, data[:, 2], width, bottom = 0, color = np.random.rand(3,))
ax.bar(index+width, [0]*len(bar_markers), width*3, bottom=bar_markers, edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

It doesn't show anything at all.

If you know the reason why, please let us know, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are not using matplotlib 3.1.1 you should be able to call `plt.ioff()` to suppress this behaviour. The `i` stands for *interactive* and Ipython interpretes it in the way that whenever a matplotlib figure is generated, it needs to be shown.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just updated matplotlib to 3.1.1. I tried `plt.ioff()` it still keeps the behavior as I described

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, "if you are not using 3.1.1,...".

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks tho. Do you have any idea of how to work around this?

Comment: If this is important for you, use matplotlib 3.1.0 until 3.2 is released and stick to `plt.ioff()`. Of course you can suppress *any* output from a cell via `%%capture`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you very much